How do I allow two different signers to modify data in a PDA?
I'm trying to understand PDAs and ultimately want to be able to have a game where two different players (each with their own wallet) can modify the game state individually (i.e. one signer). For this I've created a very simple example.

The first method initializes a boolean variable. The two accounts are passed in and set as initializer and player_two.

There is one other method, update_boolean, that allows the boolean variable to be changed if the updater is one of the accounts above.


When attempting to test initialization I get the following error:
failed to send transaction: Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: custom program error: 0x1
The program:
#[program]
pub mod boolean_test {
    use super::*;

    pub fn initialize(ctx: Context<Initialize>) -> Result<()> {
        let boolean_account = &mut ctx.accounts.boolean_account;
        boolean_account.initializer = *ctx.accounts.initializer.key;
        boolean_account.other_player = *ctx.accounts.other_player.key;
        boolean_account.boolean_value = false;
        Ok(())
    }

    pub fn update_boolean(ctx: Context<UpdateBoolean>, new_value: bool) -> Result<()> {
        let boolean_account = &mut ctx.accounts.boolean_account;
        let signer = *ctx.accounts.updater.key;
        require!(
            signer == boolean_account.initializer || signer == boolean_account.other_player,
            ErrorCode::Unauthorized
        );
        boolean_account.boolean_value = new_value;
        Ok(())
    }
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct Initialize<'info> {
    #[account(init, payer = initializer, space = 8 + 32 + 32 + 1, seeds = [b"boolean", initializer.key.as_ref(), other_player.key.as_ref()], bump)]
    pub boolean_account: Account<'info, BooleanAccount>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub initializer: Signer<'info>,
    /// CHECK: This is not dangerous because we don't read or write from this account
    pub other_player: AccountInfo<'info>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct UpdateBoolean<'info> {
    #[account(mut, seeds = [b"boolean", boolean_account.initializer.as_ref(), boolean_account.other_player.as_ref()], bump)]
    pub boolean_account: Account<'info, BooleanAccount>,
    pub updater: Signer<'info>,
}

#[account]
pub struct BooleanAccount {
    pub initializer: Pubkey,
    pub other_player: Pubkey,
    pub boolean_value: bool,
}

#[error_code]
pub enum ErrorCode {
    #[msg("You are not authorized to perform this action.")]
    Unauthorized,
}

I'm suspecting I'm not assigning player_two the proper permissions/Account type?

0x1 error means that you have insufficient funds.
Can you try airdropping yourself some SOL to the signer and updater accounts

Did not realize that I needed to airdrop myself SOL in the Anchor tests themselves. Thanks!
